# devise roles: different roles, in some cases same rights

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two roles in devise. The first is the admin and the second the normal user-role.
Now I´d like to give these two groups in some cases same rights with before filters.

How does this work?

I have:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:new, :create]
before_filter :authenticate_admin!, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

But now only a user can :new and :create...the admin not..
What I have to do here?

Thanks, 
Mattherick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't yet used Devise personally, so this is only to point you in the right direction. It might not work exactly right.

```
before_filter :authenticate_user_or_admin, :only => [:new, :create]
before_filter :authenticate_admin!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

# ...

protected
  def authenticate_user_or_admin
    unless user_signed_in? or admin_signed_in?
      # Redirect somewhere else
    end
  end
```

Comment: thanks rspeicher! I thought about nearly the same, but now it works.